# SensorEventListener in a Service seems to be causing frameskips

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, frames, sensormanager

I'm sorry if my problem seems too specific but here goes.

**What I'm trying to do:** write an app that detects falling (of old people) and sends out a notification.

**Problem:** The app gets stuck somewhere and it ends up skipping frames according to LogCat.  It also gets stuck in one state at times which may or may not be related to frame skipping.

Currently, I'm working on the part where I detect the fall and I want to change an ImageView in the UI to indicate that a fall has occured.  I've already worked out how I want to detect the fall and I'm implementing it as a state machine.

At first, I was only using a Service implementing a SensorEventListener.  This was fine for a while but unexpectedly, I began noticing frame skip notifications.  Then I read that Service runs on the main thread which seemed like the source of the problem at the time.  So after a bit of searching, I decided to try running an AsyncTask implementing SensorEventListener from the Service.  This did not help at all and clogged up the LogCat, serving to further confusion.  The app built and ran of course, but the frameskipping problem persisted and I still wasn't getting desired results.  I'd love to test if my method of detecting a fall is actually working but I can't be sure what the heck is happening with the frameskips and such.

Here's the entirety of my Service code:

```
public class DetectionService extends Service{

private static final String TAG = "DetectionService";
private static final float g_2 = 96.2361f;      // gravity squared
private static final float FREEFALL_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER = 0.21f;   // when acceleration approx. equal 4.5 m/s/s
private static final float IMPACT_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER = 2.1f;      // when acceleration approx. equal 20 m/s/s

private SensorManager mSensorManager = null;
private Sensor accSensor;
private Sensor linAccSensor;
private Sensor gyroSensor;

private Thread reporter;
private Handler handler;
private CountDownTimer debounceTimer;   // used to debounce signal
private CountDownTimer stillnessTimer;  // used for detecting stillness longer than 5 seconds

private boolean fallen = false;
private boolean timeUp = false;
private boolean isStill = false;
private int state = 1;      // 0 = fallen, 1 = detecting free fall, 2 = detecting impact, 3 = waiting 1 second, 4 = detecting stillness



public DetectionService() {

    state = 1;      // initial state, subject is fine
    fallen = false;

    stillnessTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1) {  // count down 5 seconds

        // call every millisecond
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             if(millisUntilFinished % 1000 == 0)    // every second
                 onSecondTick(millisUntilFinished);

             if(!isStill) {
                 state = 1;     // subject is probably fine, start waiting for free fall again
             }
             else {
                 state = 0;     // subject has fallen, distress signal will be asserted
             }
         }

         // call every second
         public void onSecondTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " " + "Time elapsed since impact: " + (5 - millisUntilFinished/1000) + " seconds");
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " " + "5 seconds has passed and subject has not moved.");
             timeUp = true;
         }
    };


    debounceTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

        // call every millisecond
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }

         public void onFinish() {
             Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " 1 second has passed to let subject settle.");
             state = 4;
         }     
    };

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    };

    reporter = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                   try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);         // execute every second
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    // TO DO
                    if(fallen) {
                        // send distress signal
                        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("distress"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "distress signal");
                    }
                    else {
                        // send fine signal
                        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("fine"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "fine signal");
                    }         
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    reporter.start();
    SensorTask st = new SensorTask();
    st.execute(null, null, null);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);  
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}

public class SensorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements SensorEventListener{

    private void initSensors() {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) DetectionService.this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        accSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        linAccSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        gyroSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(state) {
        case 0: 
            Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " fallen: " + fallen);
            fallen = true;
            break;
        case 1: // detecting free fall
            switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER): 

                if(detectFreeFall(event)) {
                    // free fall detected
                    state = 2;      // start detecting impact
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        break;

        case 2: // detecting impact
            switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER): 

                if(detectImpact(event)) {
                    // impact detected
                    state = 3;
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        break;

        case 3: // waiting 1 second for phone to settle
            debounceTimer.start();      // filter out the 1st second after impact to let the phone's position settle
            break;

        case 4: // detecting stillness
            debounceTimer.cancel();
            switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
            case(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE): 
                if(!detectMovementGyro(event)) {
                    stillnessTimer.cancel();    // significant change in orientation detected, stop the timer
                } 
                else {
                    stillnessTimer.start();
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        break;

        default:
            break;

        }   
    }

    private boolean detectMovementGyro(SensorEvent event) {
        float gyroX = event.values[0];
        float gyroY = event.values[1];
        float gyroZ = event.values[2];

        float sqrMag = calcSqrMagnitude(gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ);

        Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " gyro sqr mag: " + sqrMag);
        Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " gyro: (" + gyroX + ", " + gyroY + ", " + gyroZ + ")");

        if( (sqrMag > 0.2f)) {  // placeholder test value for now
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean detectImpact(SensorEvent event) {

        float accX = event.values[0];
        float accY = event.values[1];
        float accZ = event.values[2];

        float sqrMag = calcSqrMagnitude(accX, accY, accZ);

        Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " acc sqr mag: " + sqrMag);

        if(sqrMag > (IMPACT_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER * g_2)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;   
    }

    private boolean detectFreeFall(SensorEvent event) {

        float accX = event.values[0];
        float accY = event.values[1];
        float accZ = event.values[2];

        float sqrMag = calcSqrMagnitude(accX, accY, accZ);

        Log.d(TAG, "state: " + state + " acc sqr mag: " + sqrMag);

        if(sqrMag < (FREEFALL_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER * g_2)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;   
    }

    public float calcSqrMagnitude(float x, float y, float z) {
        return (float) ( Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2) );
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        initSensors();

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

If it helps illustrate what's supposed to be going on in there, this is my ASM chart https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDxcH.jpg 
The implementation in code is a little bit different; I tried having it wait 1 second to crudely filter out any movement of the device as a result of hitting the ground, rather than as actual movement of the person who fell.

So I guess my question/request is: is there anything wrong with my approach?  Can someone see if I'm making any glaring noobie errors?

Additional info: the service was getting stuck in state = 4 before I migrated the SensorEventListener component to an AsyncTask.

Comment: Having an AsyncTask implement a SensorEvent listener won't actually make it happen on another thread.  Only the code in doInBackground is called on another thread, and only when called via execute()

Comment: @Gabe Thanks for this info.  I've been googling some more, and I'm gonna try what the response in this topic suggests [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256929/android-how-to-run-your-sensor-service-thread-activity)  Just wondering if you had any opinion on his suggestion?